# Психолингвистика - tag removal or (at least) strict redifinition request

Tags: discussion, retag-request

OK, so let us take a look at following questions:

- [Аутентично ли чередование в сочетании согл. -шка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-is-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-an-authentic-stem-con). This question is indeed very bad formulated, so it had been closed.
- [Этимология слова “даже”](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-etymology-of-dazhe-even-although) - This is, as to me, a very, very interesting question.
- [What is the origin and meanining of -ка in these words](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-is-the-origin-and-meanining-of-%D0%BA%D0%B0-in-these-words-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB) - this actually looks to me like very uncertain question which have all chances to be closed, but this is not what I'm trying to point to.
- [Why мартышка but not *мартыха?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/why-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-but-not-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B0) - This is normal question. Well, not brilliant, but such questions are definitely can exist.
- [Kонцепт «хамство» по Вежбицкой](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/k%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82-%C2%AB%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%C2%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-concept-%E2%80%9Ckhamstvo%E2%80%9D-according-to-wierzbicka) - As to me this is very, very low quality question, uncertain and, let me put is straight, pseudoscientific. I'm puzzled why this question is not closed, but, once again, this is not the issue to which I want to draw your attention.

All of these questions possess the same tag, which is "психолингвистика" (psycholinguistics).

What I'm trying to say is that, just like we are fighting with low quality questions, questions which are "vague, incomplete, overly abroad", we should as well thoroughly filtrate our tags collection. I mean, in wide context, any kind of linguistic problems are somehow related to human consciousness. But I can see no valid reason why, say, the fact that there is no equivalent to "даже" in other Slavic languages should be tagged as "psycholinguistical" problem.

So, let's discuss necessity of having such tag at all. It would we nice if we'll find some relevant examples of using this tag and of asking such questions like " Хамство по Вежбицкой" on other language SE sites.

Comment: Following your logic, the tags licke 'grammar' or 'language usag' should also be removed. Or anything you don't understand.

Comment: @Manjusri, can you provide some examples of using exactly this tag on other languages SE sites?

Comment: Please avoid calling each other names. Fresh visitors to the site don't see the history of your relationships. Behave yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @Quassnoi, As for me, Im once again, fundamentally want to concentrate on questions, answers and tags, not users.

Comment: I shall reiterate, however, that we ought to focus on not on the symptoms, but on the causes, that is, certain non-constructive patterns of behaviour. Otherwise we shall be here, discussing countless questions, answers, and tags, that be repeating time and time again.

Comment: The conflict is about someone's attempt to impose wrong method on my ways of expressing myself.

Comment: @Manjusri The conflict is about rules this community, as part of SE, and adhering to SE bylaws, has imposed on itself, and the user that keeps violating these rules. If that user does not like those rules, he is welcome to go to ответы.google.ru, ответы.mail.ru and so forth where no one would stop him.

Comment: @theUg guys, you are the worst bigots I have ever stumbled upon in my life.

Comment: @Manjusri, this is one of the worst overblown hyperbolas I’ve ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

The fact something has not been used yet doesn't meen it should be closed as a tag. The rest I have already said to you earlier.

Comment: The fact that something has not been used is by itself no indicator of anything, but the fact that on MANY language SE services theres nothing like 'psycholinguistical' questions provoke some thoughts.

Comment: @shabunc Or the fact that questions so tagged make no connection to that branch of linguistics.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: I just cannot believe someone can really be so rigid in thoughts.

Comment: Demanding a proof of a statement is not a rigidity of thought. When you are going to say next that St. Thomas Anselm is a famous Russian horticulturist, am I expected to believe you, just because it is “your way of expressing yourself”?

Comment: Demaning a proof of a self-evident statement is indeed a rigidity of thought.

Comment: And someone's personal whims have nothing to do with laws or even with rules of this site. I think it takes too much efforts to remain calm here.

Comment: Oh, BTW: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psycholinguistics

Comment: I mean I don't value experience(s) much, since if all the people were doing only the things the other people do we were sitting in caves dressed in animal skins. But perhaps noticing that there are some psycholinguistical questions o Linguistics SE might make the opponents to use their mental skills.

Comment: 1) Declaring something (as you do with a lot of things) self-evident, including clearly subjective experiences, — now, that is rigidity. Mayhaps, you are yet to learn the value of healthy [scepticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism), although you seem to be quite at home on another extreme: [philosophical one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_skepticism). 2) If you would look at Linguistics.SE more thoroughly, you would see that questions that use this tag actually relate to it, not just slap it on for no reason. And that is exactly what we are talking about.

Comment: This site about Russian language is a bore.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to remove this tag.
It doesn't have a wiki and questions listed under it do not have enough in common to have their own tag.

Usually tags with science names like "physics" are used to annotate questions about terminology of these sciences. Questions about terminology in psycholinguistics can be asked under the same tag as the questions about linguistic terminology, just as questions about quantum mechanics terminology can easily go under "physics" tag.